# 1 is equal to -i

Tags: complex-numbers

Pretty simple, but I'm sure there's some subtlety to it I'm missing.

$$(-i)^2=1 \Rightarrow \sqrt{1}=-i \Rightarrow 1=-i$$

Looking at an Argand diagram however, gives some reason to doubt this.

**Edit**: as is pointed out in the comments/answers this is all kinds of wrong:

primarily, $(-i)^2=(-1)(-1)(i)(i)=i^2=-1$.

also, $a^2=b \Rightarrow \pm a=\sqrt{b}$

Comment: $$(-i)^2=i^2=-1$$

Comment: In general $\sqrt{a^2}\ne a$ (in fact this is already the case for $a=-1$)

Comment: Ah of course, dumkopf. no mystery here after all. I think I was confused by the fact that $\sqrt{-1}=\pm i$

Comment: However, you could "prove" in the same way that $-i = i$. ;) The error basically is that $a^2 = b^2$ does not imply $a = b$ (unless you assume, for example, that $a$ and $b$ are *positive* real numbers).

Answer (score 4):

There are two errors in this proof, which both have been mentioned in comments and answers, but it is worth putting them together, for completeness.

(1) It is not true that $(-i)^2=1$. Indeed, for any $x$, $x^2=(-x)^2$, so $(-i)^2=i^2=-1$.

(2) In generally, knowing that $x^2=y^2$ does not let you conclude that $x=y$. The most obvious example is $x=-1,y=1$.

Answer (score 3):

Hint:

$$
(-i)^2=(-i)(-i)=(-1)(i)(-1)(i)=(-1)(-1)(i)(i)=(i)(i)=i^2=-1
$$

so, you have ''missed'' the difference between $(-i)^2$ and $-(i)^2$

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that $\sqrt{x^2}=|x|,$ which is only $x$ for real values greater than or equal to zero.

In your case $|\pm i|=1,$ but NOT when you drop absolute values.

Comment: In complex domain your first equation is not true. Otherwise we'd get $\sqrt{(1+i)^2}=\sqrt2$.

Comment: That's why I said 'real values.'  The second equation is just a special case that applies to the OP's question. Plus, it does apply to strictly imaginary numbers, which is where the original question originates from.

Comment: No it doesn't: $\sqrt{i^2}=\pm i\ne1=|i|$.

Comment: True. I stand corrected.